# Select closest control element regardless of type (Input, Select etc.) for Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me explain:

I have a table form and some fields are required and I am trying to create custom validation.

example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="required">Description</td>
     <td>
        <input id="input1" />
      </td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>
         <input id="input2" />
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="required">Location</td>
       <td> 
         <select id="select1"/>
       </td>
       <td>Email</td>
       <td>
          <input id="input3"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

What I wanna do is find all  elements with class required
which is pretty easy using:

```
var requiredElements = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
```

And then I want to find their closest control element and check if it's value is empty. The problem is I don't know if it's gonna be input or select. I was thinking of using the .closest() function but it could lead to unwanted results if two different inputs are equally close to a required  (like in the example above).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you can't apply the "required" class to the control itself?

Comment: @Raad I initially used the required class to change the css or the labels. But I guess I could change the css specifically for the <td> elements that have "required" class and still use the class for the controls.

Comment: I just thought of another way to go, which might solve it for me. I could give each td having class "required" a custom attribute labelFor = "inputId" and by getting the value of labelFor for each of the required labels i will have the Id of the corresponding control. Nevertheless for educational purposes I would still like to get an answer on how you can select a control regardless of type (input, element etc.)

Comment: Panagiotis - in your example, I assume you would want to return `input1` and `select1` as "required" fields...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I like Raad's answer I'd like to post this answer to say what I did to solve my problem.

First of all I added a custom attribute labelFor to every label td with value equal to the id of it's corresponding input as follows:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="required" labelFor="input1">Description</td>
     <td>
        <input id="input1" />
      </td>
      <td labelFor="input2">Phone</td>
      <td>
         <input id="input2" />
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="required" labelFor="select1">Location</td>
       <td> 
         <select id="select1"/>
       </td>
       <td labelFor="input3">Email</td>
       <td>
          <input id="input3"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Then I used the following Validation function:

```
      function validateForm () {
                var self = this;
                var validationPassed = true;
                //First I will gather every .required element in an Array
                var requiredTags = document.querySelectorAll(".required"); 
                //Then I will loop through the array
                for (var i = 0; i < requiredTags.length; i++) {
//Get value of attribute "labelFor" which would be the controlId that this label refers to
                    var controlId = $(requiredTags[i]).attr("labelFor");
    //Then I use this to check if that control's value is empty.
                    if ($("#" + controlId).val() == ('' || null)) {
                        validationPassed = false;
                    }  
                }
                if (!validationPassed) {
                    alert("Please fill all the required fields");
                }
                return validationPassed; 
            }
```

This way I check if all required fields are not empty and return true, or return false and an alert to warn user.

I find that the problem Raad described in his Edit is the main reason why this approach could be more useful. You don't have to worry if your input element is always in the same position relatively to your label td element.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a control regardless of type with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) by using any one of a number of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and combining it with one or more additional selectors.

In the code snippet you provide, the controls you want to select (`input1` and `select1`) are child elements of a table cell element that is a sibling of the cell with the class "required", so we can build a selection thus:

```
$(".required + td").child
```

which breaks down as:

1. Find the elements with the "required" class applied to them.
   This will give us the 2 table cells:

   ```
   <td class="required">Description</td>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <td class="required">Location</td>
   ```
2. For each element returned by **1.** use the "next adjacent" selector `+` with `td` to get the next table cell:

   ```
   <td><input id="input1" /></td>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <td><select id="select1" /></td>
   ```
3. For each element returned by **2.** get the child element:

   ```
   <input id="input1" />
   ```

   and

   ```
   <select id="select1" />
   ```

There is also a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raad/e4fvX/2/) to illustrate actions on the targets (change border to dark red).

**Edit**
This works because the layout in your snippet consistently places the elements you want to target in the same position relative to the element with your selection criteria. You **must** have some consistent way of finding elements that are not marked with a class/id otherwise you can't achieve your objective.

Comment: +1 because you answered my question the way I initially wanted! The problem you describe in the end though is the reason why I went another way. I posted an answer if you wanna check it out and maybe comment on it. Thx again!